# How to call method on text box change event

Tags: asp.net

I have an Id in textbox and I want on behalf of id ,name should be displayed in an below another textbox.I have created an method but don't know where to call it..
Whenever I select the id,the below textbox should automatically be filled with an name of that particular Id..

Please Help me...

Comment: What have you tried?  What code can you show?  Have you looked around for resources on ASP.NET Textbox event handlers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this:**(Double click on textbox at design view)**

```
    void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateGrid(textBox1.Text);
    }

    void PopulateGrid(string queryStr)
    {
       //here you can write the binding code
    }
```